# How does `Tiered compilation` effect .NET Core 3.0 application and when shall I disable it?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, compilation, .net-core-3.0

From Microsoft's [.NET Core 3.0 new features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#tiered-compilation), it mentioned:

> Tiered compilation (TC) is on by default with .NET Core 3.0. This feature enables the runtime to more adaptively use the Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler to get better performance.
>
> The main benefit of TC is to enable (re-)jitting methods with a lower-quality-but-faster tier or a higher-quality-but-slower tier. This helps increase performance of an application as it goes through various stages of execution, from startup through steady-state. This contrasts with the non-TC approach, where every method is compiled a single way (the same as the high-quality tier), which is biased to steady-state over startup performance.

The document gives two different ways to compile. But it didn't mention how to decide and switch between the compile options.

So how will the `TC Compiler` switch between the two modes and effect our code? How dose this effect our applications while migrating from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.0? When shall I disable this feature?

Comment: I think the [linked blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/tiered-compilation-preview-in-net-core-2-1/) have both diagrams and carefully phrased paragraphs on the details. There are also design docs from the actual repo, https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/tiered-compilation-guide.md